# Question & answer disappeared.

Tags: support

I posted a rather detailed answer to a calculus of variations problem last night, and can find no trace whatsoever this morning. I was hoping to save the answer for myself.

I cannot find the question nor can I find any hint that it was deleted, etc.

Is there some way to (1) get hold of my answer and (2) look for deleted questions (even if only by title)?

(Ideally I would save my posts, but that would require a level of organization I do not possess. And I hate to see that work gone to waste.)

Comment: Depending on your surfing preferences, you may still find a link in your browser's history. For a few disappearing questions, I've had to do that.

Comment: But I use 'private browsing' when on Stackexchange so my wife doesn't know I was here...

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Seriously, thanks for the suggestion, I will look!

Comment: I think that [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/337602) is the question you answered.

Comment: Your suggestion was a good one. I have recovered everything.

Comment: @robjohn: How (the hell) did you find it?

Comment: (How should I close out this question?)

Comment: Sorry for the comment trail, thanks for the follow up on the question.

Comment: @copper.hat: I have undeleted the question. It looks as if the OP was trying to hide the question.

Comment: @copper.hat you don't need to close it out, but I have converted my comments to an answer if you want to keep your accept rate up :-)

Comment: @robjohn: Excellent thanks! (How did you locate the deleted post?)

Comment: @copper.hat: moderators can search for deleted posts. However, I thought at 10K or 20K I could see deleted answers on my profile. Maybe that was just the answers that I deleted, not answers that were to questions that were deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337602) appears to be the question that you answered. I have undeleted it since it appears that the OP might be trying to hide that they asked the question. Whether or not that is the case, it should not be deleted.